# Accessing A MySQL Database In Silverlight (C#)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, silverlight, web-services

I am trying to access a MySQL database in a [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net) application. I have tried to reference to System.Data.Services to access the SQLClient class, but it says:

> You can't add a reference to
>   System.Data.Services.dll as it was not
>   built against the Silverlight runtime.
>   Silverlight projects will only work
>   with Silverlight assemblies.

I have also tried to add a reference to MySQL.Data, but received the same error.

I have read online that I will need to use a WebService, but I do not know how to make one.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, I am targeting PHP and MySQL servers, not ASP, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access sql through php:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/PHP-MySQL-and-Silverlight-The-Complete-Tutorial.aspx

Comment: @Alem yay! (plz select the ans as correct then - check next the message)

Answer (score 3):

Alem, Silverlight is a client-side technology.

It will only work in browsers. You cannot just make direct call to a database from your Silverlight app.

First off, this would be a major security issue you don't want to deal so fortunately you are not even allowed to.

Use webservices, or even better: WCF services.
Try this link: http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/silverlight-and-wcf/

Hope this helps.